# What is the structure of a std::vector?

Tags: c++, recursion, stdvector

I have made a recursive way of printing all of the elements of a vector, but it returns nonsense! and it throws a really strange exception:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >::operator[](...) returned nullptr.
```

And it outputs: `12358000`

This is the code. What is the mistake I have made?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int printVec(vector<int>* foo) {
    if ((*foo).empty())
        return 0;
    else {
        cout << (*foo)[0];
        printVec(foo + 4);
    }
}
int main() {
    vector<int> ref{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 };
    printVec(&ref);
}
```

Comment: what makes you believe that `(*foo)[0];` or `printVec(foo + 4);` is valid c++ code?

Comment: `&ref` is a pointer to a single vector. You cannot increment it to get anything meaningful

Comment: @idclev463035818 It is valid, is it not?  As long as `foo` is a valid pointer to `vector<int>`, which on the initial call to `printVec` it is.  The problem is that in the recursive call, it is pointing to a `vector<int>` which doesn't exist; `&ref` only points to one such vector, not 4 or any larger number.

Comment: What I tried to do: dereference the pointer foo and get the first element of the vector(why is that flawed?) and in the second one; call vector with foo starting on the next 4 bytes.

Comment: @NateEldredge `(*foo)[0];` is ok only on the first recursion, after that all bets are off

Comment: @OriónGonzález: `foo+4` doesn't give you the 4th next element of the vector.  It gives you the 4th next vector in a hypothetical array of vectors, of which `foo` pointed to the first one.  This is the normal behavior of pointer arithmetic in C++. But you never constructed any such array - or if you like, `&ref` points to an array of size 1 - so you are off the end of it.

Comment: If you want to be operating on a different chunk of the same vector, you should be using iterators instead of pointers.

Comment: You might find it interesting to know ... using g++ 9.3.0 on lubuntu 20.04 ... the sizeof (vector<T>) is 24 bytes,  independent of how many elements (yes, even when size() == 0),  and independent of how big each element is.  The vector<T> is a 24 byte object, the elements contained by the object are actually in dynamic memory, and std::vector<T> manages the memory for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the mistake I have made?

You are using a pointer to a single vector and treat it as if it points into an array of `std::vector<int>`. It is only allowed to increment pointers that point to elements in arrays (actually you are allowed to get a pointer one past an object, but not more). A single `std::vector` is not an array and your code invokes undefined behavior by incrementing `foo` here: `printVec(foo + 4);`.

If you want to "point to" elements of the vector use iterators:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename IT>
void printVec(IT current, IT end) {
    if (current == end) return;
    else {
        cout << *current;
        printVec(current+1,end);
    }
}
int main() {
    vector<int> ref{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 };
    printVec(ref.begin(),ref.end());
}
```

> What is the structure of a std::vector?

You need not know nor care. If you want to iterate elements use iterators. If you want to access the underlying array use [`.data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data).

Answer (score 5):

`foo` is a pointer to a `std::vector<int>`.

`foo + 4` is adding 4 lots of `sizeof(std::vector<int>)` to `foo` in pointer arithmetic. There is not a `std::vector` at that location, so the behaviour of `printVec(foo + 4)` is undefined.

The expression `(*foo)[0]` is calling the overloaded `[]` operator on a `std::vector` which access the first element in the vector. If there is no element at that position then the behaviour of the program is undefined.